# Good and simple approach to convert XHTML to Word Doc/Docx for MVC .ASP.NET Web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, xhtml-1.0-strict

I am looking for a good and simple approach to convert a XHTML document into a Word Document within a ASP.NET MVC3 application.

I am aware of a number of components like Syncfusion's DocIO and Aspose, but wondered whether I was missing a simpler option.

I am doing the formatting in the XHTML, so really this is about converting XHTML to Word.

EDIT

I am rather thinking that an approach may be to get the result from a Razor transformation ie View(myModel) and add a mime type of MS-Word, something like:

```
string myXHtml = View(MyModel)
```

Then add the "application/msword" header context code and return. I have just understood this was easy in Webforms, but more tricky in MVC. Just researching, but open to ideas.

Thanks,

Sam